# JavaScript loop through two arrays and get single array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays:

```
var arr = [ 
  { id: 2, username: 'bill'}, 
  { id: 3, username: 'ted' }];

var b = ["ted", "bill", "john"];
```

how can I get one array like this:

```
var finalArr = [{id: 2, username: 'bill'},{id:3, username: 'ted'}. {id:0, username: 'john'}]
```

If user from array `b` exist in `arr` array to add id and if not id to be 0.

I tried something like this, but not working

```js
var arr = [{
    id: 2,
    username: 'bill'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    username: 'ted'
  }
];

var b = ["ted", "bill", "john"];

var finalArr = [];

function userExists(username) {
  var a = arr.some(item => {
    if (item.username === username) {
      finalArr.push({
        username,
        id: item.id
      })
    } else {
      finalArr.push({
        username,
        id: 0
      })
    }
  })
}

b.forEach(el => {
  userExists(el)
})

console.log(finalArr)
```

Comment: do you need the given order: bill, ted, john?

Comment: Does Id is a generic property ? that means, could be a chance that in the future there could be more names under b array, would you like the Ids to be generic ?

Comment: @Xerox33 : What if you happen to have multiple entries with the same `username` and different `id` within your `arr`? If you're not willing to remove those duplicates, you might check out my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Loop through `b` using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Check if the `username` exists in `arr` using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find). If yes, return the object. Else, return a new object with `id: 0`

```js
var arr = [ 
  { id: 2, username: 'bill'}, 
  { id: 3, username: 'ted' }];

var b = ["ted", "bill", "john"];

const output = b.map(username => {
  const found = arr.find(a => a.username === username);
  return found || { username, id: 0 }
})

console.log(output)
```

Comment: you change the order.

Comment: @NinaScholz yeah. Since OP used `b.forEach`, I assumed that was not important

Answer (score 1):

You can use map and find to construct your new array like

```js
var arr = [{
    id: 2,
    username: 'bill'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    username: 'ted'
  }
];

var b = ["ted", "bill", "john"];


const finalArr = b.map(username => {
  const find = arr.find(o => o.username === username);
  return find ? find : { id: 0, username }
})

console.log(finalArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using *reduce* method.

```
b.reduce((result, elm) => {
    const userObj = arr.find((a) => a.username === elm);
    if(userObj) {
        result.push(userObj)
    } else {
        result.push({
            id: 0,
            username: elm
        });
    }
    return result;
}, []);
```

Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce for more details about reduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can craete a dummy array for storing result and , find the existing using `find`. If not found create dummy object and push inside array.

```js
var arr = [ 
  { id: 2, username: 'bill'}, 
  { id: 3, username: 'ted' }];

var b = ["ted", "bill", "john"];
myArr = [];
b.forEach(function(element) {
var el=arr.find(x => x.username === element);
  if(el){
    myArr.push(el);
  }else{
    var dummy={};
    dummy.id=0;
    dummy.username=element;
    myArr.push(dummy);
  }
});
console.log(myArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Set` and filter by looking to the set and delete visited items. At the end concat missing items.

This solution repsects the order of the given data and adds the missing object in order of the `names` array.

```js
var data = [{ id: 42, username: 'foo' }, { id: 2, username: 'bill' }, { id: 3, username: 'ted' }],
    names = ["ted", "bill", "john"],
    missing = new Set(names),
    result = data
        .filter(({ username }) => missing.delete(username))
        .concat(Array.from(missing, username => ({ id: 0, username })));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```